# MongoDB giving error while importing JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to import JSON file of 1.1GB into MongoDB using the command:

```
mongoimport -d sis -c Final --file C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\Final.json\Final.json
```

After successful insertion of the documents, suddenly an error popped up on the screen:

```
2017-01-25T21:31:00.746+0530    Failed: error processing document #795796: unexpected EOF
2017-01-25T21:31:00.749+0530    imported 795795 documents
```

I do not know why it is showing 148MB only while importing, where as I have 1.1GB of records available.
Still I have many records to be inserted. But MongoDb is failing to import. Why is this happening? How can I avoid this mishap situation?

Comment: Any problems with "document #795796" ? Unescaped quotes? EOF symbols?

Comment: Is the json in the file valid? you can check using an online utility such as http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @AlexBlex I have checked that but there wasn't any issue with it. No EOF symbols nothing as such.

Comment: @AmanB The Json is valid. If it wasn't then how the other documents where getting inserted in MongoDB? There might be a problem with the line as specified in the error. But do not know what it is. and the tool you suggest, I don't think that it gives proper output of JSOn what is required as an input to MongoDB

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is with the source file, but without a reproducible example it would be a guess job. If I were you, I'd try to take off the problematic document. It may worth to check if the error the same on another system. E.g. spin up a small  instance of EC2/DO/etc and try to import it there.

Comment: @AlexBlex sure I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing one \Final.json

mongoimport -d sis -c Final --file C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\Final.json\Final.json

to

mongoimport -d sis -c Final --file C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\Final.json